# Implement/integrate ESLint in SonarQube?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, yaml, eslint

I would like to ask how can I implement the ESLint on our Azure Pipeline? I do not have enough knowledge on Azure Pipelines and SonarQube, and I also am not so sure about ESLint. So far, here's the script I have. Although this is pretty much from the available tasks. I'd like to implement the ESLint on SonarQube like on this link: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11639183

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
      checkLatest: true
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
    displayName: 'NPM Install'
    
  - script: |
      npm bin -g
    displayName: 'Check path'

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'test' #from the package.json
```

This one here is from the npm bin -g:

```
##[debug]   /home/vsts/work/_temp/5b2e34ae-e8f8-4e24-a539-9d41f7435789.sh
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/5b2e34ae-e8f8-4e24-a539-9d41f7435789.sh
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.23.1/x64/bin
##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool '/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/bin/bash'
##[debug]task result: Succeeded
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;done=true;]
```

Here's the error from the last task.

```
##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory=/home/vsts/work/1
##[debug]rm -rf /home/vsts/work/1/npm
##[debug]removing directory
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
```

Here's a bit of copy from my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run lint:lwc && npm run lint:aura",
    "linter": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./",
    "lint:aura": "eslint **/aura/**",
    "lint:lwc": "eslint **/lwc/**",
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not tasks or commands in your yaml pipeline to run the linter. You can add a script task or npm task to run the linter. See below:

Add a npm task to run linter.

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
  displayName: 'NPM Install'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Linter'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run linter'
```

Or add a script task to run linter:

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
  displayName: 'NPM Install'

- script: |
    npm run linter
    npm run lint  #run npm run lint:lwc && npm run lint:aura in your package.json
```

Before you can run above linter commands in azure pipeline. You need to add eslint dependency to your project and generate your ESLint config file on your local machine.

Run below commands on your local repo and then push to your source server.

Add eslint dependency:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

Generate ESLint config file

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

You can check out [this blog](https://dev.to/paulasantamaria/improving-your-ci-pipeline-for-node-js-2aab).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I was able to proceed forward. Although I still encounter the error. I have the .eslintrc and I have pushed it to the root folder. (where the package.json as well) However, I still encounter error. Sorry for this. I am fairly new in Azure and ESLint.

##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]

Comment: Nevermind, I have just added continueOnError on the task. But I'd like to ask why is it throwing an error though?

Comment: @PercyJackson There might be some thing wrong with your tests. You can troubleshoot the more detailed log by [Enabling system diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs)